# There is a weird border around my gnome programs, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: fedora, gnome, cinnamon, gtk

[image]

Example is gnome disks, but all of my gnome programs have that weird border on the outside, how can I get rid of it?

This is on Fedora 24 cinnamon in case it matters.